# Primefaces Datatable Rowkey

Tags: primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.5 and I want help on the following issue:

I have a datatable with selection mode single and the selected item is the bind to an object instead on a specific object property. Sample code below:

```
<p:dataTable id="name" value="#{bean.items}" var="item" selectionMode="single" selection="#{bean.selected}" rowKey="#{item}">
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" />
<p:ajax event="rowUnselect" />
...
</p:dataTable>
```

During item creation, I don't persist the item to database immediately, instead I maintain a list of items and during action save handler I persist the whole list.

The issue is that for every newly created item I don't generated the object id(is done on database automatically on persist) and during row selection on the table the selected item is always wrong. Can I manage correct row selection without having a unique object property?

Answer (score 1):

Thats is problem **logical**, if you use **autogenerated key** change method **equals/hashcode** to other fields because when you use a autogenerated you must have **candidate key**.

Comment: So is impossible without any unique key on the object. I was thinking about using object hashcode but I have to change all my entities. I will try with random generator value and before persist stage I will set it to null in order for the database to take care of it. Is this solution the best practice? What to you suggest?

Comment: read good practise equals and hashcode https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode